# Maven3 - How do I found dependency resolution? ( mvn depedency:tree does not work for mvn3 )

Tags: maven, maven-3

With maven-3, it uses aether to resolve dependency.

Unfortunately, "mvn dependency:tree" use legacy (maven-2) resolution engine.

How do I find out the true dependency resolution for maven-3.  I'm running into an issue where "exec:exec" creates different classpath then "dependency:tree".

In [maven 3 - compatibility notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-DependencyResolution), it says I need to use "-X" and look at the log but there is no pointer what to look for.

Also, "assembly:assembly" brings in different 'jar' than when I print out classpath from "exec:exec".

Answer (score 2):

`dependency:tree` is the correct way to get the project dependencies. Since version 2.5 of the plugin it now resolves the tree using aether.

`exec:exec` runs the maven exec plugin.  The `classpath` it generates is based on the *plugin dependencies*, if specified.  It is relevant only for the purpose of the plugin execution and not to be taken in the context of project.

The similar explanation holds good in case of `assembly:assembly`.  The jars that it brings in entirely depends on the plugin and assembly-descriptor configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post pom.xml.  But if you follow the link in to "compatibility notes", you will see that they are different.  I need to know what is easy way to see dependency resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.5 of the Maven Dependency Plugin, `dependency:tree` works with Maven 3 (see the [bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-339), and the [release notes](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=11214&version=18077))