# maven 3 dependency plugin - inconsistent result

Tags: maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I am migrating my project from maven 2 (2.2.1) to maven 3 (3.1.0) and I am having some issues with jar versions. When I tried to track down the problem, I experienced some inconsistent results from *dependency plugin* which confused me.

When I tried the following commands in **maven 3**:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=commons-codec
```

the results was:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ xxx ---
[INFO] com.xxx.yyy:zzz:war:2.6-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- net.sourceforge.jwebunit:jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin:jar:2.2:test
[INFO]    \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.5:test
[INFO]       \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

so the result suggest **commons-codec-1.3.jar** will be used. (maven 3 does include commons-codec-1.3.jar when packing).

However, if I add the option (-Dverbose) to the command

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=commons-codec -Dverbose
```

the result will be

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ xxx ---
[INFO] com.xxx.yyy:zzz:war:2.6-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.jwebunit:jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.5:test
[INFO] |     +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |     |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:test - omitted for conflict with 1.3)
[INFO] |     \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- xxx.yyy.zzz.core:www-core:jar:2.6-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    \- xxx.yyy.zzz.security:datasecurity:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO]       \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The second result suggests that the version **1.2** and **1.3** will be omitted due to conflict, and maven will use **1.6**. Apparently it was not the case since **maven 3** packaged **commons-codec-1.3.jar** in the war file.

Why did the plugin in maven 3 suggest different dependencies in two cases (It should not as -Dverbose should only show which dependencies omitted and why)? Is it a bug or am I missing something?

It is worth to note that **maven 2** will package with **commons-codec-1.6.jar**.

P/s:

- Since version 2.5 of the Maven Dependency Plugin, dependency:tree works with Maven 3 - [Maven3 - How do I found dependency resolution? ( mvn depedency:tree does not work for mvn3 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425910/maven3-how-do-i-found-dependency-resolution-mvn-depedencytree-does-not-wor)
- verbose:     Whether to include omitted nodes in the serialized dependency tree. - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes)

Comment: Thanks, I did. I understood that in some cases the dependencies can be resolved different between maven 2 & maven 3. What I don't understand is "Why the plugin suggested different dependencies in two cases just because of "-Dverbose").

Answer (score 0):

Maven always is the closest dependency [that match](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html), in this case 1.2, 1.3 and 1.6 are of the same level of depth: 3. So Maven has to chose one of them and takes 1.6.

You could force a given dependency version by **adding the dependency directly in your module pom.xml** which would make it in the **first level of depth** and force maven to use it with the version you defined.

Furthermore, this seems strange to me that you expect version 1.2 since it is a transitive dependency of one the test dependencies (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:**test**), this should never be packaged.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually I expect 1.6 and that is what maven 2 is current doing. I also expect the plugin shows the consistent results with/without -Dverbose. Anyways I rephrase my question to make it more clear.